# Rails - Ordering by the association date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following two models:

```
class Shelf < ActiveRecord::Model
    has_many :wines

    def self.order_by_oldest_bottle_of_wine
        #TODO: order by the oldest wine bottle...
    end
end

class Wine < ActiveRecord::Model
    belongs_to :shelf

    attr_accessible :produce_date
end
```

In the shelf model, I want to order shelfs by the oldest wine bottle on the shelf (i.e. shelf with the oldest wine bottle first), but not 100% sure of the implementation.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3.x you can use any one of the following

**Solution 1:**

```
def self.order_by_oldest_bottle_of_wine
  self.wines.order("produce_date DESC")
end
```

**Solution 2:**  If you want to use scope

```
class Wine < ActiveRecord::Model
  belongs_to :shelf
  scope :ordered_by_produce_date, order("produce_date DESC")
  attr_accessible :produce_date
end

class Shelf < ActiveRecord::Model
  has_many :wines
  def self.order_by_oldest_bottle_of_wine
    self.wines.ordered_by_produce_date
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this through a named scope

In your `Shelf` model you could defined it like so:

`named_scope :order_by_oldest_bottle_of_wine, joins: :wines, order: "wines.produce_date DESC"`

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.order_by_oldest_bottle_of_wine
    self.wines.find(:all, :order=>"produce_date DESC")
 end
```

Comment: ideally I would like to ordering of active record rather then to resort to plain sort.